# I have a iOS 7 iPad. I am stuck on Guided Access

Tags: ios, safari

I am stuck on Guided Access on my iOS 7 Apple iPad. Help ?!?!

Comment: Please provide more detail... who enabled the Guided Access?  What have you tried doing already?  Has it done this before? ... ?

Comment: I have found holding the home/power button down until the Apple logo appears to be an effective fix when there is a malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

If this does not work, turning on and off the iPad generally turns off Guided Access.  If the iPad does not allow you to hold down the power button then slide the switch off, then holding down the power and home buttons to restart the iPad should cause this to stop, as [bassplayer7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/18917/bassplayer7) said.

Answer (score 0):

You can end a Guided Access session

- Triple-click the Home button.
- Enter the Guided Access passcode.

If that doesn't work, you might need to restore the device or get the hardware fixed (assuming the home button is the failure and not that you don't know the passcode).